# Python pandas map pivot back to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

what I am trying to do is use the map function to tie back a pivot table to another dataframe. A1:A4 are columns that denote a different location. So the value in the pivot table represents the # of instances at A1 or A3, etc.

I have one dataframe and one pivot table. The dataframe (df1) looks like this:

```
    SubscriberKey Inst    A1   A2   A3   A4
        'abc'      1      0    0     0    0
        'bcd'      2      0    0     0    0
        'cde'      1      0    0     0    0
        'def'      3      0    0     0    0
        'efg'      0      0    0     0    0
```

My pivot table (pt1) looks like this:

```
                 Instance Instance Instance Instance
   SubscriberKey    A1       A2       A3       A4
        'abc'       1         0       2        0
        'bcd'       0         1       1        2
        'cde'       1         1       0        0
```

I would like to somehow populate my df's A1:A4 columns based on what is in the pivot. The df has more subscriber keys than the pivot table contains and so the row counts are not the same.

The output would look like:

```
    SubscriberKey   A1  A2     A3   A4
        'abc'       1    0     2    0
        'bcd'       0    1     1    2
        'cde'       1    1     0    0
        'def'       0    0     0    0
        'efg'       0    0     0    0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you need to reword the question and/or show the desired output since your statement  "The df has more subscriber keys than the pivot table contains and so the row counts are not the same." is not true for the sample you give. Based on what you said, you might want to use the `reindex` method.

Comment: hi @JoeCondron. sorry about that I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample you give, you can do

```
pt1['Instance'].reindex_like(df1.drop('Inst', axis=1)).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

You should probably inspect the output of each step in this computation to give an idea of how it works.